# Excel-Vba: How to convert range of numbers to the sequence of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have to convert range of numbers in a cell to sequence of numbers  in a column as below:

`10&-2&&-5&-8` to

```
10
12
13
14
15
18
```

I don't have any idea about that. Please help to give me some ideas.
Thank you very much.

Comment: try to edit your example... it is not clear how the conversion should work. Also: What did you try so far? stackoverflow is for specific coding questions, not freelance service.

Comment: What do the ampersands represent?  Why miss 11, 16 & 17?  Why end at 18?  _Why????_

Comment: Sorry, I will describe more details about my issue: I want to convert the range of numbers like 10&-2&&-5&-8 = 10&12&&15&18 = 10&12&13&14&15&18. The "&&" symbol presents the list of sequential numbers with the start number in the left and the end number in the right. Thanks.

Comment: Posted a solution assuming a fixed pattern of four parts using the `Split` function and tried to decipher the unusual logic therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution assuming a four part string**

Assuming you have a fixed pattern of always four parts and your string is delimited by `"-"`, I deducted the following logic using the `Split` function and a user defined helper function:

- (i)   first number                (=absolute 10 out of string "10&")
- (ii)  starting number of sequence (=increment 2 to first number = 10 + 2 = 12)
- (iii) ending number of sequence   (=increment 5 to first number = 10 + 5 = 15)
- (iv) last number                 (=increment 8 to first number = 10 + 8 = 18)

**Example code**

The following code splits the somewhat bizarre string **"10&-2&&-5&-8"** into four parts, calculates the main numbers, assigns the defined sequence including the first and last element to an array and writes values back to a column.

```
Sub WriteSequence()
  Dim s As String, i As Integer, ii As Integer
  Dim first As Long, last As Long, start As Long
  Dim vParts, v      ' variant
' string example
  s = "10&-2&&-5&-8"
' tokenize string parts
  vParts = Split(s, "-")                ' split at delimiter "-"
' get main numbers
  first = getNumber(vParts(0))          ' get first number
  start = getNumber(vParts(1)) + first  ' calculate start number (from)
  ends = getNumber(vParts(2)) + first   ' calculate ends  numnber (to)
  last = getNumber(vParts(3)) + first   ' calculate last  number
' write to array
  ReDim v(0 To last - first + 1)
  v(0) = first
  For i = 1 To ends - start + 1
      v(i) = start + i - 1
  Next i
  v(i) = last
' write back to sheet
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[A2].Resize(i + 1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)
End Sub
```

**Helper function**

```
Function getNumber(ByVal s As String) As Long
' Purpose: return a number from a string ending with "&" or "&&"
getNumber = Val(Split(s, "&")(0))
End Function
```